# Pi3B stuck in busybox

Tags: crash

this weekend I setup a pi3b. It hosts several servers: kodi, node-red, grafana, mosquitto, influxdb and maybe some more. In other words, the absolute minimum a gentleman needs in its house!

OS is rpi-OS 2023-10 32bits. It is install on a SSD.

After a reboot, and rpi os splash screen, it is stuck with  this message:

[image]

**Keyboard is non functionnal. What should I do? Can I get some logs somewhere that can be helpfull?**

I ran:

```
smartctl -a /dev/sdX
```

with the SSD drive plugged in another linux system and no errors were detected.

**I'm pretty sure this has nothing to do with the issue but here are what I did today with it before reboot:**

I tried to automate kodi startup and added a service like this:

```
sudo tee -a /lib/systemd/system/kodi.service <<_EOF_
[Unit]
Description = Kodi Media Center
After = remote-fs.target network-online.target
Wants = network-online.target

[Service]
User = pi
Group = pi
Type = simple
ExecStart = /usr/bin/kodi-standalone
Restart = on-abort
RestartSec = 5

[Install]
WantedBy = multi-user.target
_EOF_

sudo systemctl enable kodi.service
```

I also did some adjustments in kodi (elect external sound card and maybe other things).

Comment: Start again.  Add software back until boot fails.